# When was getcharstr() introduced? And how could I have found the answer my self from :help?

Tags: help-system, history-of, version

Yesterday I made [a change](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ/commit/e4a209a785de2bd9caffbdc3eaf9eea509c2b78f) to [my plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ) which essentially consisted in using `getcharstr()` instead of `nr2char(getchar())`.

That was Vim 8.2.4106.

Today at work I updated my plugin and got an error, because `getcharstr` doesn't exist. This is Vim 8.2.1123.

When was `getcharstr` introduced? I had no luck in `:help vim8`, nor by `grep`ping the repository (because I was `grep`ping my fork which was not up-to-date, silly me).

Besides, is this information even available in a Vim installation (in the form of release notes or something)? Or how should I find it from the repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was patch [v8.2.2957](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2957), which can be found by examining a full clone of github.com/vim/vim and any of

```sh
# message search; fast enough I didn't need any of the other limiting options
git log -1 --grep getcharstr
```

but if it's not in the commit messages…

```sh
# patch search
# very slow
git log --oneline --reverse -Sgetcharstr | head -n1
# for example, limiting the range of versions to search from "bad" to "good"
git log --oneline --reverse -Sgetcharstr v8.2.1123..v8.2.4106 | head -n1
# knowing that the new function is in `runtime/doc/eval.txt`:
git log --oneline --reverse -Sgetcharstr v8.2.1123..v8.2.4106 -- runtime/doc/eval.txt | head -n1
# this might be the fastest patch search, knowing it's likely to be in `src/getchar.c`:
git log --oneline --reverse -Sgetcharstr v8.2.1123..v8.2.4106 -- src/getchar.c | head -n1
```

Comment: **IS** there any way to learn this without having a full clone of the source?

Comment: I'm not aware of one in general. The list of patches in `:help vim8` is sorely out of date. But you can always test for existence with `has` and `exists`

Comment: @mcwayliffe there is a plugin https://github.com/tweekmonster/helpful.vim which gives the command :HelpfulVersion getcharstr, that shows the same version as this answer